# Building DNN architectures, ML models, and training pipeline via GUI nodes

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning

Is there any solution/attempt for creating DNN training pipeline, arch through GUI nodes?

E.g. something similar to Blender node editor (image below).

[image]

EDIT: I will add here list of interesting findings:

- [Perceptilabs](https://www.perceptilabs.com/home): based on Tensorflow

Comment: Try first and ask later. Every OOPL is capable to create such a thing. The question is only that how much effort you want to invest ?

Comment: I am not asking if it is possible to create one. Just curious if there is anything available before I (if) start working on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did some research and here are my findings in random order. All of them have some GUI based approach. I would say that Perceptilabs is "the closest answer" to the question.

---

- Perceptilabs

  - https://www.perceptilabs.com/home
- AutoML

  - https://medium.com/towards-artificial-intelligence/automl-a-gui-application-to-make-ml-for-everyone-31d18ca84d89
- Weka

  - https://waikato.github.io/weka-wiki/downloading_weka
- PI Exchange

  - [https://www.pi.exchange](https://www.pi.exchange/)
- Nvidia Digits

  - https://developer.nvidia.com/digits
- Orange

  - [https://orange.biolab.si](https://orange.biolab.si/)
- RapidMiner

  - [https://rapidminer.com](https://rapidminer.com/)
- Azure

  - https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/machine-learning/
- AWS

  - https://aws.amazon.com/machine-learning/
- DeepExcel

  - [http://www.deepexcel.net](http://www.deepexcel.net/)
- Deep learning studio

  - [https://deepcognition.ai](https://deepcognition.ai/)
- Neural network console

  - [https://dl.sony.com](https://dl.sony.com/)
- Ennui

  - [https://math.mit.edu/ennui](https://math.mit.edu/ennui/)

---

Nice overview and table comparison of few solutions
https://towardsdatascience.com/making-deep-learning-user-friendly-possible-8fe3c1220f9

Other discussions
https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/218099/is-there-a-visual-tool-for-designing-and-applying-neural-nets-deep-learning

Comment: Just a comment on Orange: it does not support DNN outside of a simple MLP widget. It is intended more for prototyping and data exploration than for building NN.